# how can i add select and update an image from a php dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php dropdown menu that currently does not update and set the selected choice when one is made

it is populated from a database, I would like to be able to get the value of the selected choice so i can update the picture of the persons face (face to go with name)  also need to know how to set selected option to just the selected option instead of to every one in the list
here is what i have

```
$SQL = "SELECT id, name, facePic FROM people";
echo "<option>Select one</option>";
$res = $db->query($SQL);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $img = $row['facePic'];
    echo "<option value=".$id.">".$name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

any help is greatly appreciated

ps. i dont mind if i have to do it with something other than php as long as my dropdown is still populated from db

also i am planning to have the img show in a separate div but still in the same form

Comment: Please add your SQL Query. What is the value of `$SQL`?

Comment: any specific reason to  echo the same value twice ?

Comment: How do you know what value the user has selected? Where/how are you saving it?

Comment: PedroLobito thanks for pointing out the echo i just typed it wrong          

Twisty i added the sql query                 

Victory I dont know how to store it  i thought it was supposed to somehow add selected to the selected choice but am not sure how to go about doing that it never seems to update unless i submit my form (which i would like to wait till its finished to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you plan to do with 'facePic' as I don't see it in your output. For your PHP:

```
echo "<option>Select one</option>";
$res = $db->query($SQL);
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value='{$row['id']}' pic='{$row['facePic']}'>{$row['name']}</option>\r\n";
}
```

Then in your JQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("select").on("change", function(){
    $("#targetImage").attr("src", $(this).find("option:selected").attr("pic"));
  });
```

});

Comment: thank you so  much you put me on the right track i ended up just using javascript but without this answer i would not have knows where to go

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to update a picture based on the value of a dropdown?

If so then what you could do is use jQuery like so:
(Let's say that the image tag has an id #image and that the image names are in this form id.jpg")

```
var image_src = $("select").val();
$("#image").attr("src", image_src);
```

Of course if you want to use the actual values that are displayed to the user ($name in your case) then instead of using

```
$("select").val();
```

you would need to use

```
$("select option:selected").text();
```